# How to ensure that unhandled exceptions which kill Tasks are logged or rethrown on the main thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

When a thread running a `Task` is killed by an unhandled exception, that exception is not propagated back to the calling thread until `Task.Wait()` is called.

The problem:

When the `Task` in question is long-running, particularly when its lifetime is the same as the lifetime of the parent object, it can be long-dead by the time `Task.Wait()` is called. This makes it difficult to debug unhandled exceptions occurring on those long-running tasks.

Is there a way to ensure that these unhandled exceptions are (quickly) logged or, preferably, rethrown on the calling thread, without relying on a call to `Task.Wait()`?

Here is a minimal example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskExample
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main()
      {
         var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
         //start our long-running task
         Task LongTask = Task.Run(() => LongRunningOperation(source.Token), source.Token);

         //assume our application runs indefinitely, or until shut down
         while (true) {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Still running the application.");
         }
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// This method must run continuously for the lifetime of the application. 
      /// If exceptions are thrown here, they are difficult to debug because they are
      /// not rethrown on the calling thread.
      /// </summary>
      public static async Task LongRunningOperation(CancellationToken token) 
      {
         while (true) 
         {
            try
            {
               //check for cancellation
               token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
               //Do some work on an interval
               Console.WriteLine("Doing some work.");
               await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
               //this exception is not seen by the main thread 
               throw new Exception();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Long running operation was canceled by caller.");
            }
         }           
      }
   }
}
```

I'm not asking how to catch a specific exception that might occur in `LongRunningOperation()`. Obviously, I can write a particular `catch` clause in that instance.

I'm asking about a more general approach that ensures that any exceptions which are uncaught will throw on the calling thread, in the name of "fail fast," or at least be logged quickly.

Comment: Sure. You can `await` the Task straight away, and do something sensible if it completes with an exception (such as rethrowing it on the threadpool, which will crash you app, or passing it to a suitable handler). You can do the same by putting a try/catch around the body of the `Task`-returning method

Comment: @canton7 What about a task that needs to run for a long time, such as a socket poller? I can't necessarily tie up the calling thread with a `Task.Wait()` call, or block the method's progress with an `await`.

Comment: `await` doesn't tie up a thread, that's kind of the point.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my comment to clarify. I know `await` doesn't tie up a thread, but it does block progress in a method until a thread returns to the context.

Comment: Only if you when await the resulting `Task`. Think about it this way: `Operation()` can throw an exception. So you define `public void SafeOperation() { try { Operation(); } catch (Exception e) { ... } }`. That's sensible and normal. Now do the same with Tasks. You still end up with a Task which needs to be waited at the end of execution (or just use an `async void` method if that meets your needs), but you've gained error handling

Comment: I'm not quite visualizing what you're describing. Do you have an example you can point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was to use a Continuation Task via `Task.ContinueWith()`.

Here's a code snippet from [David Haney's blog](https://www.davidhaney.io/tpl-and-error-handling-continuations/) that I found very helpful.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        // Initialize a Task which throws exception
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception("It broke!");
        });
        // Configure the Continuation to only fire on error
        task.ContinueWith(HandleError, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        // Start the Task
        task.Start();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("End of method reached");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void HandleError(Task task)
{
    // The Task has an AggregateException
    var agex = task.Exception;
    if (agex != null)
    {
        // Output all actual Exceptions
        foreach (var ex in agex.InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how I applied the solution to my minimal example. Note that I have somewhat simplified the reporting of the faulted `Task`'s inner exception.

```
   class Program
   {
      public static void Main()
      {
         var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
         //start our long-running task
         Task LongTask = Task.Run(() => LongRunningOperation(source.Token), source.Token).
            ContinueWith(TaskErrorHandler, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
                  
         //assume our application runs indefinitely, or until shut down
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Still running the application.");
         }
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Used as a continuation task to handle errors for any tasks that
      /// complete with the "faulted" state.
      /// </summary>
      /// <remarks>Pass this as a continuation option only with <see cref="TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted"/>
      /// to ensure that it is not invoked unless the antecedent task threw an unhandled exception.</remarks>
      /// <param name="t"></param>
      public static void TaskErrorHandler(Task t) 
      {
         //log the inner exception from the task. Note that
         //we do not need to check for null here, as long as 
         //this method was passed to ContinueWith() with TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted
         Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.Flatten().InnerException);
      }
      /// <summary>
      /// This method must run continuously for the lifetime of the application. 
      /// </summary>
      public static async Task LongRunningOperation(CancellationToken token) 
      {
         int i = 0;
         while (true) 
         {
            
            try
            {
               //check for cancellation
               token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
               //Do some work on an interval
               Console.WriteLine("Doing some work.");
               await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
               //this exception is not seen by the main thread 
               if (i == 2)
                  throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("value of i was too big!");
               i++;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Long running operation was canceled by caller.");
            }
         }           
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got several options.

The easiest is just to make your method `async void`. Now, `async void` is generally frowned upon, for two reasons:

1. If any exceptions occur, they are immediately rethrown on the thread pool. This might be what you want however!
2. You don't get a `Task` back, so you can't tell when your operation has finished. This might not matter, e.g. for fire-and-forget scenarios, but you might care about knowing when your `Task` has completed before you finish shutting down.

If those are acceptable to you, you could write (assuming you've got the method `Task DoThingAsync()` which returns the `Task` you're worried about monitoring):

```
public async void DoThingAndRethrowExceptions()
{
    await DoThingASync();
}
```

---

If those points aren't acceptable to you, you can still add in some error handling, but still return a `Task` which indicates whether the operation has completd:

```
public async Task DoThingAndRethrowExceptionsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await DoThingAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Do something sensible with the exception. Maybe you just want to crash your app,
        // in which case rethrowing it inside an async void method is an easy way to do
        // this.
        // Or maybe you want to rethrow it on the UI thread in order to give your app a
        // chance to display an error screen: invoking the dispatcher and rethrowing it is
        // an easy way to do this.
        // Or maybe you want to pass it to a callback, or log it, or... Up to you!
    }    
}
```

The `Task` returned from `DoThingAndRethrowExceptionsAsync` will never complete with an error: it will just complete when the `Task` returned by `DoThingAsync` completes, either successfully on shutdown or earlier if it threw an exception.

If you decide to rethrow the exception, of course don't just do `throw e;` as this will nuke the stack trace. Either throw a new Exception with `e` as the InnerException, or use `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e).Throw()`.

Comment: Problem with returning `void` instead of `Task` is that you're throwing away the async state machine **including its call stack**, which means that the runtime won't be able to fill in the stack trace information correctly.

Comment: @IanKemp Are you sure? [This example disagrees](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J7vZSZ)

Comment: So in my current usage, I'm calling `Task.Run(ExampleMethod())` from a constructor. If I instead define `ExampleMethod()` to be something like `public async Task ExampleMethod() {await DoWork();}` and simply call `try {ExampleMethod();}<catch statement>` from my constructor, then the constructor will continue execution after `ExampleMethod()`, which will run asynchronously, and any exception thrown in `DoWork()` will be caught in the constructor?

Comment: Probably? It's unclear why you were using `Task.Run` with a method which is actually properly async, so I'm not 100% sure I understand what you were doing

Comment: I think I just had a gap in my understanding of how to use `async` methods. I apologize for being unable to show my code. 

Alternatively, if I don't use a `try`, then the exception would be thrown in the constructor, correct?

Comment: So if your `ExampleMethod` returns a `Task`, and that `Task` could complete with an exception, but you throw that `Task` away, then no, if that `Task` ends up containing an exception you'll never know. Notice how the code in my answer awaits the `Task` inside the `try`. I don't know what your constructor has to do with this I'm afraid. It's very possible to create a [mcve] which represents your code without containing your actual code, and indeed this is expected on SO

Comment: You are right, I've updated the question with a minimal example